# JQuery autocomplate based on two database fields returning the primary one

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have database with fields `name` and `alias` I want the autocomplete to check both fields and than return the matches of the `name` field. So far I managed to make the autocomplete to look for the `name` field. Here is the code:

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({

              source: function(request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                  url: "http://example.com/ajax/auto",
                  data: {
                          term : request.term
                   },
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(data){
                     var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                          return obj.name;
                     });

                     response(resp);
                  }
              });
          },
          minLength: 1,
          open: function() {
              var position = $("#ui-id-1").position();
              var left = position.left;
              var top = position.top;

              $("#ui-id-1").css({top: top - 35 + "px" });

          }
});
```

Question is how to implement the `alias` field into the code so it can return the `name` upon finding match in the `alias`.

This is what `http://example.com/ajax/auto` servers:

`{"id":1,"name":"NewYear","alias":"New Year","created_at":"2019-10-30 10:10:18"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to pass both field in the back end and check at backed side with or condition.

In front end side code:

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({

              source: function(request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                  url: "http://example.com/ajax/auto",
                  data: {
                          name: request.name,
                          alias: request.alias
                   },
                  type: 'post',
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(data){
                    //your code
                  }
              });
          },
});
```

And If it is return by any database query then it may like:

```
select name from table where name = name_param or alias = alias_param;
```

Comment: In the json link I am serving data like this: `{"id":1,"name":"NewYear","alias":"New Year","created_at":"2019-10-30 10:10:18"}` both fields are there, I think I have to implement somehow the logic to the javascript `.autocomplete` function. In this example the goal is to always serve `NewYear` no matter if one types `New Year` or `NewYear`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try this out.

Comment: Read my answer properly. Specially sql query.

Comment: You are a life saver!! It turns out that the jquery code I have was working perfectly fine! The problem came from the SQL query, I had to add the OR clause and now I am searching for a match in both fields. Thank you very much sir!!